No SSH connection possible after server restart
I've restarted my server today and now I cannot connect to it anymore using SSH. When I try to connect to it using Putty it times out. I don't get the possibility to enter my user name. (VNC connection is possible).
Things that I've tried so far:

disable UFW
disable SSHD fail2ban
reinstall SSHD
restart server
SSHD service is started
netstat shows that ssh daemon service is listening on port 22.
a site hosted on this server is working.

Rather curious. I've managed to connect once a few minutes a go for a few seconds after changing /etc/ssh/ssh_config . ForwardX11 was commented out. I've enabled it. But that's it. (ForwardX11 is still enabled, I've checked it).
This is the output from trying to connect to it using Powershell:
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname x.x.x.x is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x[x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:000002A1EF440000
debug1: connect to address x.x.x.xport 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection timed out

Edit: update, I'm able to enter again. No idea what caused it. My idea is that the data center where the VPS is hosted had some issues today. Not sure if that's true though. Because VNC and the sites hosted on my vps were working.

FYI changes to /etc/ssh/ssh_config would affect the Ubuntu ssh client (ssh), not the server (sshd)

Ah, so that doesn't affect me trying to ssh into it then. Clear

That's correct. Have you double checked that x.x.x.x is the right IP address?  Is it possible that there is another device on the network with a conflicting IP (sometimes happens if you have a mix of static and DHCP addresses). Are you trying to connect from within the same LAN or from outside?

Yes. The IP address is right. Just checked it again. I'm trying to connect from outside. A conflicting IP from inside my own LAN? Not sure how to check it, but it is unlikely. When I ping I reach the server. I did manage to reach the server for a few seconds as I managed. Could it be that something running on my server is causing the timeout?
